# Drupal cron - only one task running

Tags: drupal, cron

How I configure Drupal cron to ensure that the task will only run if no other task running?

The file /var/www/html/drupal/cron.php it is by default.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the tasks are mutually exclusive ie: One can't run after the other one finishes. You should configure those tasks as a single one and have them run subsequently. Otherwise you could use hook_cron to validate if the second task is running and schedule the current task for a future time until it finishes.

Hope this helps

Bewilled.